# Centos - how do I install a specific version of Erlang?

Tags: centos, erlang

I'm running Centos 6.7 on my server and am trying to install Erlang/Rabbitmq following these instructions:

- [Erlang Installation](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html)
- [RabbitMQ Installation](https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/install)

The trouble is that at time of writing these install Erlang 19.0 with RabbitMQ 3.6.3, which leads to a [pretty major bug](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/244) as far as my client who occasionally looks at the management interface to monitor queues is concerned.

The guidance in the error ticket is not to use erlang 19 until RabbitMQ 3.6.4 is released. But how can I install a specific version of Erlang?

Comment: Have you tried downloading an earlier version package from [here](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html) or installing using the *Installation using repository* instructions below?

Comment: As far as I understand the specific packages need specific commands which I cannot see in the instructions. The same goes for the manual setup where it explains how to add a reference to the erlang repositories instead of using the rpm file for this. However I cannot see how it picks a specific version.

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me:

1. Go to the download page here: https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/
2. Select your appropriate package -- you can copy/peek the link then download it using `wget`.
3. Install it using `rpm`.

Example:

```
# Download erlang 19
$ wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/site/esl/esl-erlang/FLAVOUR_1_general/esl-erlang_19.0~centos~7_amd64.rpm

# Install
rpm -Uvh esl-erlang_19.0~centos~7_amd64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always build install from source.

Go to the [Erlang.org Downloads](https://www.erlang.org/downloads) page, pick your version from the right side.

From there you can follow the instructions. Although they are for Ubuntu, the commands are the same except for the *dependencies* part where you can use the command below to install what you need:

```
sudo yum install g++ openssl-devel unixodbc-devel autoconf ncurses-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl), which is similar to rvm in some sense and very (very!) easy to use. It will let you install different Erlang versions and switch between them any time you want.

I prefer this approach instead of looking up packages myself (with possible incompatibilities in the dependencies required) or downloading and compiling everything myself every time I want to try a new Erlang version.